# Writing and documenting a Python script with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, scripting, documentation, arguments, argparse

I am new to Python and I would like to run a script by passing a variable number of arguments. That is, from my terminal window I would like to run the same command as-like the followings:

```
// Case1
python script.py arg
// Case2
python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg3 arg4 ... argN
```

In Case1 I know how to do that but I don't know how to make the script to handle the case with multiple and variable arguments passed (Case2). How can I?

---

Bonus: How to document the above behavior through the `argparse` module?

Comment: Straight from [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html): `nargs='+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    print arg
```

This print all the arguments given from the command line.

If you would like to use `argparse`, you can do:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='View arguments')
parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs='+', help='passed arguments')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.arguments
```

Comment: +1 for argparse. There are plenty of examples on google. Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv[2:]` should do what you need it to get all 1 - N input arguments in a list

**Edit: Example Code**

Here's a quick script:

test.py hi hello test

*Code:*

```
import sys
l = sys.argv[2:]
print l
```

*Prints:*

`['hello', 'test']`

If you want to get all the input arguments, you can do:

*Code:*

```
import sys
l = sys.argv[1:]
print l
```

*Prints:*

`['hi', 'hello', 'test']`

Comment: Can you be more prolific, perhaps with a script example? I do not how to use what you wrote in order to handle multiple arguments inside the script.

Comment: @Backo Yup. just added